# Custom Session Handler in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, memcached

What are the best practices to follow in writing custom session handlers? I have gone through most of the existing PHP frameworks and most of them seem to have problems with concurrency and multiple ajax requests when handling session id updates. The default PHP sessions use file locks to manage this, but there doesn't seem to be a proper way to do this if I am using, say, mysql to store sessions. What would be the best way to solve this issue? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if you could simulate locking in database?

Answer (score 1):

If you won't lock session files/another storage row you can lose the data.

Simple scenario (assuming you have dropped the locking completely):

The initial state: there is a page with 2 ajax-requests run simultaneously, each of which adds another key to the session:

1. Request A sent
2. Request B sent
3. Script A reads the session to the memory, it's empty
4. Script B reads the session to the memory, it's empty
5. Script A adds key A to the session. Now it contains single A key (in memory)
6. Script B adds key B to the session. Now it contains single B key (in memory)
7. Script A persists the data
8. Script B persists the data

Result: A key is lost

So - if you want to guarantee the data in session is consistent - you need to have some synchronisation mechanism. Which may be, for example, pessimistic lock, but still, you cannot avoid lock completely.